# How to include screenshot like "Send Feedback" activity in Google+

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I want to create an activity similar to the "Send Feedback/Report and Issue" page on Google+. Is there an api to capture the screenshot, or is this manufacturer dependent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch FeedbackActivity in my application like in Android Hangouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644933/launch-feedbackactivity-in-my-application-like-in-android-hangouts)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no exposed API for accessing the screen buffer. You may find some success in using `View.getDrawingCache(boolean)` which returns a `Bitmap` of the `View` which you may then be able to save and use.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache(boolean)